# Azure VM connect button doesn't download RDP on new provision

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

The connect button doesn't seem to download the RDP. I've stopped and restarted the VM. I've tried to ping the IP and it doesn't respond but the azure portal shows that the VM is running. I'm running Windows server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't download the RDP file, you can use "**mstsc**" to login the VM. In Azure, the IP can't ping, you can **use telnet to test the connection**, windows VM will open port 3389 by default, so you can telnet 3389.
If you want to download the RDP file, you can try to use another browser.

Comment: Thanks! it worked, chrome blocked the download. Edge popped up a download bar.